# How To Bypass Call By Reference

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code:

```
myList.Add(new Model(1, "David"));

Model m = myList[0] as Model;
m.name = "Leo";

MessageBox.Show(myList[0].name);
```

`MessageBox` shows me 'Leo' while I except see 'David'.

How can I see 'David' as Result without deleting this line:

```
m.name = "Leo";
```

Thanks.

Please help me thanks.

Comment: You literally changed the value of that property. Why should it say "David"?

Comment: I suspect you've already got items in your list. `Add` places a new item at the end, and you're getting `[0]` which is the first item.

Comment: And what’s the point

Comment: We need a more concrete example.. The only answer that makes sense with what we are shown is to delete `m.name = "Leo";`. If you don't want "Leo", never assign it..

Comment: I think you want a "deep copy" or "deep clone" of `myList[0]` so that `m` is not the same reference as David. Give "clone" a Google.

Comment: You need to create a new `Model`.

Comment: Are you intending to create a new `Model`  and insert it into the `List<T>`? Or what do you want to do with the existing `Model` instance? You *are* obviously changing the `Name` of it.

Answer (score 1):

Classes as reference types are fundamental to the .NET framework, so you can't just "bypass" it. If you want `m` do be a *different* instance that what's in the list, then you need to *clone* the instance rather then just getting a reference to it. There are many ways to do this, and that's not what you want, so I'll leave it to you to research how to do that. Or if you want to preserve the original properties somehow, put them in variables before you change the properties:

```
    Model m = myList[0] as Model;

    string oldName = m.Name
    m.name = "Leo";

    MessageBox.Show(oldName);
```

Bit I also suspect that this isn't what you want to do.

The main point is that there's no way to simply "treat" reference types as value types.